# Placement system isn't working Roblox Studio Lua

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make a script for roblox studio lua placement system script. When trying to get it to snap to grid I can only build off of a pre-existing block on the -X and +Z directions. On any other direction it will just snap to the block I'm trying to build off of. However I can build of the floot fine.

And yes, I'm going to make this server sided as soon as I figure out how to get the snapping to work.

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local mouse = player:GetMouse()
local mousePosition = mouse.Hit

local function Snap(gridSize)
    local posX = math.floor(mouse.Hit.X / gridSize + 0.5) * gridSize 
    local posY = math.floor(mouse.Hit.Y / gridSize + 0.5) * gridSize
    local posZ = math.floor(mouse.Hit.Z / gridSize + 0.5) * gridSize
    print("Input:")
    print(mouse.Hit.X)
    print(mouse.Hit.Y)
    print(mouse.Hit.Z)
    print("Result:")
    print(posX)
    print(posY)
    print(posZ)
    return Vector3.new(posX,posY,posZ)
end

mouse.Button1Down:Connect(function()
    
    local part = game.ReplicatedStorage.part:Clone()
    part.Position = Snap(4)
    part.Parent = game.Workspace
    
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a LocalScript and a RemoteEvent for this, because the Server cannot access the `LocalPlayer`, nor it can get it's `Mouse` object.

You can rewrite the code like this:

LocalScript

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local mouse = player:GetMouse()
local mousePosition = mouse.Hit


local function Snap(gridSize)
    local posX = math.floor(mouse.Hit.X / gridSize + 0.5) * gridSize 
    local posY = math.floor(mouse.Hit.Y / gridSize + 0.5) * gridSize
    local posZ = math.floor(mouse.Hit.Z / gridSize + 0.5) * gridSize
    print("Input:")
    print(mouse.Hit.X)
    print(mouse.Hit.Y)
    print(mouse.Hit.Z)
    print("Result:")
    print(posX)
    print(posY)
    print(posZ)
    return Vector3.new(posX,posY,posZ)
end

mouse.Button1Down:Connect(function()
    
    (Remote event location):FireServer(Snap(4))

end)
```

Server Script:

```
(remote event location).OnServerEvent:Connect(function(Player, pos)
    local part = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("part"):Clone()
    part.Position = pos
    part.Parent = game.Workspace
end)
```

This should work for your case.